# Retarded potential for continuous and point charge distribution

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

For non static continuous charge distribution, the retarded potentials, Griffith say are;

$$V (\mathbf r,t)= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int \frac{\rho (\mathbf r',t_r) }{ (r-r')}d\tau'$$

And,

$$\mathbf A(\mathbf r,t) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int \frac {\mathbf J(\mathbf r',t_r) d\tau'}{(r-r')}$$

And then we get the Jefimenko's equations for the electric and magnetic fields by the usual:

$\mathbf E = -\nabla V -\partial \mathbf A/\partial t$

$\mathbf B = \nabla \mathbf \times \mathbf A$

HOWEVER, for nonstatic **point** charges, we use Liénard-Wiechert Potentials where there is a correction factor for $d\tau$:

$$\tau' = \frac {\tau}{\left(1-\frac { \mathbf {(r-r')}}{(r-r')}\right) \cdot \mathbf v/c }  $$

Where $\frac { \mathbf {(r-r')}}{(r-r')}$ is a unit vector from the point source to the object.

Thus, the potential is,

$$V(\mathbf r,t)= \frac {qc}{4\pi\epsilon_0((r-r')c- \mathbf {(r-r')}\cdot \mathbf v)} $$

Then Griffith says, to calculate the electric field now, we can use Jefimenko's equations.

My doubt is in Jefimenko's equations, for continuous charge distribution, the fields were
derived without this correction factor. Then how can we get the equation for fields of point charges using those of continuous charge distribution? Also, why was this correction not included while calculating the potentials in the case of continuous charge distributions?